# Using a controlgroup to group a select and a text input

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery mobile and am attempting to put a select element to the left (but joined up with) a text input element. I see that I can do something similar with button elements when using a control group as shown in http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/buttons/buttons-grouped.html .

```html
<div data-role="controlgroup">
    <select>
        <option>Option A</select>
        <option>Option B</select>
    </select>
    <input type = "text">
</div>
```

However when I run this the text input disappears and only the select options show. Is this there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to include text input within control group http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/jWv4s/

Comment: Did my solution not work for you? If it did, can you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely possible, and is outlined here, under [Textinputs](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/controlgroup/). This comes with one caveat, I have to manually re-size the text input's parent padding to make it look "correct" in the final product like this:

```
 $('yourTextInput').parent().css({ 'padding': '0.125em' });
```

Not to hijack the thread, but does anyone know why this is necessary?